# How to use dependent filters on AG-Grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, angular-filters, ag-grid-validation

I am facing problem while implementing Dependent Filter in my angular application using AG-Grid. For example : there will be three filters on a Grid, One is for Country, second is for State and the third one is for City. When I click and Select Country, then based on Selected Country my State Column should get visible in Grid and should have all the State data in it based on the Country selected. Same goes with State and City as well.
It would be helpful if someone can share the example of it or any link/article which can be a help to implement this feature.
Thank You.

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: @robert Actually I don't have anything, I've read the documentation of AG-Grid as well, But Did not  find anything in it.